# How to convert irregular list of list to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this irregular list:

```
['6', '20553737100', '6', '20431084172', '25200.00', '4536.00', 'PEN', '09', 'EG01', '124', '2022-06-20', '29735.43', ['POLO MANGA LARGA T L', '600.00', '16.90', '19.942', '1825.20', '10140.00', '18.00'], ['POLO MANGA LARGA T M', '600.00', '16.90', '19.942', '1825.20', '10140.00', '18.00'], ['LENTE LUNA CLARA TSG-100 ANTIEMPAÑO SIMPLE', '800.00', '2.65', '3.127', '381.60', '2120.00', '18.00'], ['LENTE LUNA OSCURA TSG-100 ANTIEMPAÑO C/CORDON', '800.00', '3.50', '4.13', '504.00', '2800.00', '18.00']
```

I would like it to look like this in a dataframe:

```
0       6   20553737100 6   20431284172 25200   4536    PEN 09  EG01    124 2022-06-02  29735.43    POLO MANGA LARGA T L    600 16.9    19.942  10140   1825.2  18
1       6   20553737100 6   20431284172 25200   4536    PEN 09  EG01    124 2022-06-02  29735.43    POLO MANGA LARGA T M    600 16.9    19.942  10140   1825.2  18
2       6   20553737100 6   20431284172 25200   4536    PEN 09  EG01    124 2022-06-02  29735.43    LENTE LUNA OSCURA TSG   800 2.65    3.127   2120    381.6   18
3       6   20553737100 6   20431284172 25200   4536    PEN 09  EG01    124 2022-06-02  29735.43    LENTE LUNA OSCURA JAE   800 3.5 4.13    2800    504 18
```

Sorry for the incomplete question a moment ago, apparently my list of lists is more complex.

Comment: How does it generalize? Is there always only 1 list with more values? If not can you provide an example?

Comment: you have completely changed your input. Why should all the answerers re-write their work?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It was my mistake to exemplify the list incorrectly, I learned a lot anyway, thanks

Comment: @Raknaros I see you are trying to accept several answers, note that you can only choose one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate input list in 2 parts to construct 2 dataframes which are then concatenated:

```
lst = ['6', '20553737100', '6', '20431084172', '25200.00', '4536.00', 'PEN', '09', 'EG01', '124', '2022-06-20', '29735.43', ['POLO MANGA LARGA T L', '600.00', '16.90', '19.942', '1825.20', '10140.00', '18.00'], ['POLO MANGA LARGA T M', '600.00', '16.90', '19.942', '1825.20', '10140.00', '18.00'], ['LENTE LUNA CLARA TSG-100 ANTIEMPAÑO SIMPLE', '800.00', '2.65', '3.127', '381.60', '2120.00', '18.00'], ['LENTE LUNA OSCURA TSG-100 ANTIEMPAÑO C/CORDON', '800.00', '3.50', '4.13', '504.00', '2800.00', '18.00']]
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({f'column_{i}': v for i, v in enumerate(lst[:12], 1)}, index=[0]),
                pd.DataFrame(columns=[f'column_{i}' for i in range(13, 13 + len(lst[12]))],
                             data=lst[12:])], axis=1).ffill()
print(df)
```

---

```
  column_1     column_2 column_3     column_4  column_5 column_6 column_7  \
0        6  20553737100        6  20431084172  25200.00  4536.00      PEN   
1        6  20553737100        6  20431084172  25200.00  4536.00      PEN   
2        6  20553737100        6  20431084172  25200.00  4536.00      PEN   
3        6  20553737100        6  20431084172  25200.00  4536.00      PEN   

  column_8 column_9 column_10   column_11 column_12  \
0       09     EG01       124  2022-06-20  29735.43   
1       09     EG01       124  2022-06-20  29735.43   
2       09     EG01       124  2022-06-20  29735.43   
3       09     EG01       124  2022-06-20  29735.43   

                                       column_13 column_14 column_15  \
0                           POLO MANGA LARGA T L    600.00     16.90   
1                           POLO MANGA LARGA T M    600.00     16.90   
2     LENTE LUNA CLARA TSG-100 ANTIEMPAÑO SIMPLE    800.00      2.65   
3  LENTE LUNA OSCURA TSG-100 ANTIEMPAÑO C/CORDON    800.00      3.50   

  column_16 column_17 column_18 column_19  
0    19.942   1825.20  10140.00     18.00  
1    19.942   1825.20  10140.00     18.00  
2     3.127    381.60   2120.00     18.00  
3      4.13    504.00   2800.00     18.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a cross merge:

```
l = [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'],[[5],[9],[7],[4]]]

(pd.DataFrame(l[:4]).T.merge(pd.DataFrame(l[4]), how='cross')
   .set_axis([f'column_{i+1}' for i in range(5)], axis=1)
 )
```

Output:

```
  column_1 column_2 column_3 column_4  column_5
0        a        b        c        d         5
1        a        b        c        d         9
2        a        b        c        d         7
3        a        b        c        d         4
```

Another idea using a custom function to unnest the original list:

```
def unnest(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[0]
    return [unnest(x) for x in l]

pd.DataFrame([unnest(l)]).explode(4, ignore_index=True))
```

Or, programmatic variant to avoid having to specify the columns to `explode`:

```
(pd.DataFrame([unnest(l)])
   .pipe(lambda d: d.explode(list (d.columns[d.iloc[0].str.len().gt(1)]), ignore_index=True))
 )
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  a  b  c  d  5
1  a  b  c  d  9
2  a  b  c  d  7
3  a  b  c  d  4
```

Comment: Same idea. `l = sorted(l, key=len)
pd.DataFrame(l[:-1]).T.merge(pd.DataFrame(l[-1]), how='cross')`

Comment: @SomeDude The `sorted` is a nice addition, I wanted a programmatic solution without cluttering the code, this should do it!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the solutions that they gave me, step by step and that's how I found this solution:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(filas[:12])
.T
.merge(pd.DataFrame(filas[13:17]), how='cross')
.set_axis([f'column_{i+1}' for i in range(19)], axis=1))
```

So it is as follows

```
  column_1     column_2 column_3     column_4  column_5 column_6 column_7 column_8  ...   column_12                                      column_13 column_14 column_15 column_16 column_17 column_18 column_19
0        6  20553737100        6  20431084172  25200.00  4536.00      PEN       09  ...  2022-06-20                           POLO MANGA LARGA T L    600.00     16.90    19.942  10140.00   1825.20     18.00
1        6  20553737100        6  20431084172  25200.00  4536.00      PEN       09  ...  2022-06-20                           POLO MANGA LARGA T M    600.00     16.90    19.942  10140.00   1825.20     18.00
2        6  20553737100        6  20431084172  25200.00  4536.00      PEN       09  ...  2022-06-20     LENTE LUNA CLARA TSG-100 ANTIEMPAÑO SIMPLE    800.00      2.65     3.127   2120.00    381.60     18.00
3        6  20553737100        6  20431084172  25200.00  4536.00      PEN       09  ...  2022-06-20  LENTE LUNA OSCURA TSG-100 ANTIEMPAÑO C/CORDON    800.00      3.50      4.13   2800.00    504.00     18.00
```

Thanks for everything

Comment: Please take some time to upvote/accept @mozway answer as you got help from that answer and also it will help others looking for similar questions.